# Dynamically build expression to filter Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean-expression

I need to filter an array based an a variable number of items in another array. 
Say my array to be filtered looks like this :

```
var toBeFiltered = [
  {name:"A", parentId: 0},
  {name: "B", parentId: 3},
  {name: "C", parentId: 0},
  {name: "D", parentId: 1},
  ...
]
```

I need to filter all the elements for which `parentId` is in another array (say : `var filtering = [3,1,0]`, but it can have any length).
How can I build a filter expression dynamically based on the content of the `filtering` array ? In this case I'd end up with this expression :

```
function(d){return d.parentId == 3 || d.parentId == 1 || d.parentId == 0;}
```

Is there any smart way to do this ? Something like concatenation of boolean expressions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` method which checks if an `item` exists in a given `array`.

`indexOf` method returns first occurrence of the specified value and returns `-1` if the `value` is not found.

```js
var toBeFiltered = [
  {name:"A", parentId: 0},
  {name: "B", parentId: 3},
  {name: "C", parentId: 0},
  {name: "D", parentId: 1},
  {name: "E", parentId: 4}
]
var filtering = [3,1,0];
toBeFiltered=toBeFiltered.filter(a=>filtering.indexOf(a.parentId)!==-1);
console.log(toBeFiltered);
```

Also you can use `Set` feature from `ES6`.

```js
var toBeFiltered = [
  {name:"A", parentId: 0},
  {name: "B", parentId: 3},
  {name: "C", parentId: 0},
  {name: "D", parentId: 1},
  {name: "E", parentId: 4}
]
var filtering = new Set([3,1,0]);
toBeFiltered=toBeFiltered.filter(a=>filtering.has(a.parentId));
console.log(toBeFiltered);
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. I hadn't thought about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could take [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var toBeFiltered = [{ name:"A", parentId: 0 }, { name: "B", parentId: 3 }, { name: "C", parentId: 0 }, { name: "D", parentId: 1 }],
    filtering = [1, 0], // to prevent to get the same array as the original
    result = toBeFiltered.filter(o => filtering.includes(o.parentId));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you. I accepted the other answer because includes is less supported than indexOf.